# Quarkus prevent user from login using OIDC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openid-connect, quarkus

So currently I am using `Quarkus` and the `quarkus-oidc` library to do authentication against Google IDP I set up. Which works great!

But what I want to do is basically make it so that only folks I invite will be able to register new accounts.

Now I can pretty easily put some logic on the registration endpoint for this, but I also want to fail the OIDC flow so I don't have to check this in every other endpoint everytime I get a new call.

Is there a way during the first redirect I can have `Quarkus` call a method where I can validate the email and potentially fail the flow?